# Syntax highlighting in MS Word document

Tags: c++, c, ms-word, syntax-highlighting

I want to insert some C/C++ source code into a Microsoft Word document. I have no problem in copying the code from source file and pasting into Word. I can do fixed-width. But, in Word, I see the code in black-and-white format; I loose the syntax highlighting as I get in the source code editor (for me, gvim). So, my question is, is there any way to do syntax highlighting of C/C++ source code in MS Word?

Comment: http://www.planetb.ca/2008/11/syntax-highlight-code-in-word-documents/

Answer (score 58):

I found [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v5.9.8.html) also can copy the code as .rtf file.
***Plugin/NppExport/Copy RTF to Clipboard***,
Then you can paste them into word with highlight and layout.

Answer (score 9):

I've found a tool similar to this found by darlinton, but having several different styles of colouring: http://tohtml.com/. 
I hope it would help.

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage the syntax highlighter that is in use at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). I mean the text area where you add the content to be posted to the site :)

But for a more robust and configurable solution you could check out the syntax highlighter developed by Alex Gorbatchov ([link](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter)). But well, installing it requires some knowledge of HTML and CSS. So, if I needed a quick solution to format my output, I would opt for [planet.ca](http://www.planetb.ca/2008/11/syntax-highlight-code-in-word-documents/), as [darlinton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113229/darlinton) and [ArunSaha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278326/arunsaha).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using a different editor for this job, you could load your code into [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html), use the **Edit / Copy as RTF** command, and then paste into Word.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Eclipse CDT or Visual around they do it automatically for you when you paste code to Word (Or similiar).
I assume it's not best solution for a gvim guy, but still. Just so you'll know.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching, I also found [Highlight 2.9](http://wareseeker.com/download/highlight-2.9.rar/7ccef3bed). But that requires (a) installing an application, and (b) [subjective] aesthetically I like the output of [planetb.ca](http://www.planetb.ca/2008/11/syntax-highlight-code-in-word-documents/) 's output (the answer provided by darlinton)

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, you can use the popular *highlight* package. It can output RTF file. You can copy-paste the result in Word or LibreOffice.