# How to give color to your code in open-office-writer?

Tags: python, colors, syntax-highlighting, openoffice-writer

I have code blocks written in Open Office Write and want colorize it. How can I do this?

EDIT: When I copy syntax-highlighted code back to open office writer it becomes black again. How can I change this?

Comment: Is it because you are using OO as your code editor? Don't. Is it because you want to publish syntax colored code samples in broader document? That will take some fiddling... (or I could just let Mark Byers post an answer;)

Comment: Editors, please add `open-office` and `syntax-highlighting` tags. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556862/syntax-highlighting-in-ms-word-document

Comment: @msw OO isn't my editor. :) Don't worry.

@Xavier Ho
I forget the word syntax-highlighting. English isn't my mother tongue. Sorry and thanks! My question isn't a duplicate. How can I get syntax highlighted OO?

Comment: No worries. Sounds like you found your solution?

Comment: I had some trouble with installing the plugin coooders. But now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to take a look at [coooder plugin](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/coooder) for LibreOffice(OpenOffice).

Comment: But nothing happens when I click the <> button.

Comment: @BozhidarBatsov Your link is now dead. I realize it has been four years since you posted it though :) However it would perhaps be more useful to future readers if you included the name of the plugin in your answer instead of just an "anonymous" link. I can see from the URL that it is 'coooder' and thanks for that it's what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [pygments](http://pygments.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I know this works for MS Word, but it may also work for Open Office.

http://www.planetb.ca/2008/11/syntax-highlight-code-in-word-documents/