# Copy Notepad++ text with formatting?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Notepad++ to write code.

How do I copy code in Notepad++ along with its formatting to paste into Microsoft Word? (i.e. syntax highlights, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax highlighting in MS Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556862/syntax-highlighting-in-ms-word-document)

Answer (score 324, accepted):

Here is an image from notepad++ when you select text to copy as html.

[image: Notepad++ Plugin: Copy as HTML]

and how the formatted text looks like after pasting it in OneNote (similar to any other app that supports "Paste Special"):
[image: How it looks like when importing it]

Comment: "Export to HTML" works but not "Copy HTML to clipboard". Do you know why?

Comment: A shortcut is to use:  Ctrl + Shift + C.                                                         Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Plugin Commands > Copy all Formats to clipboard. >  CTRL+SHIFT+C -->  Happy formatting !

Comment: @Pacerier As of 7.2.2 "Copy HTML to clipboard" seems to work just fine.

Comment: anyone loose Line Feed using this method?

Comment: @BobNoobGuy I am when I try to use "Copy HTML to Clipboard" (I'm on 7.2.2). Although hackish, the way I preserve line feed is by exporting to HTML, opening the HTML in Word, then copying from there to whichever source I need to send code to (e.g. OneNote).

Comment: this method is no longer preserving the format color

Comment: NppExport version 0.2.8 was not pasting the syntax formatting colors for me.  I am happy that updating to 0.2.9 fixed the colors. :-)

Answer (score 76):

Taken from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/60760/syntax-highlighting-in-microsoft-office-word):

> You can use Notepad++ to accomplish this in three ways. Just so you
>   know, Notepad++ is a more advanced version of Notepad, which supports
>   syntax highlighting of different code files "out of the box" - PHP
>   included!
>
> Download & install it, fire it up, and load up your PHP file. You
>   should automatically see it beautifully coloured (if not, because the
>   file extension is something other than .php, go to Language -> PHP or
>   Language -> P -> PHP).
>
> If you need to change any of the colours, you can easily do so - just
>   go to Settings -> Styler Configurator. From that menu, you can change
>   the various highlighting and font options, to suit your needs -
>   although the default usually suffices for most.
>
> Then, go to Plugins -> NppExport. From there, you have three options
>   you can consider:
>
> Export to RTF Export to HTML Copy all formats to clipboard Start with
>   the last one - "Copy all formats to clipboard" - which will copy the
>   entire file with the highlighted syntax to the clipboard. Once you
>   click it, then open Microsoft Word, and just hit paste! You should see
>   the beautifully syntax-highlighted code. If something goes wrong, then
>   you can try one of the other options (export to RTF/HTML), although
>   I've never had a problem with the clipboard method.

Comment: And now go to [Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Plugin Commands > Copy all Formats to clipboard] and set it to CTRL+SHIFT+C --> Instant joy. CTRL+C to copy the raw text, CTRL+SHIFT+C to copy with formatting. This should be default.

Comment: for paste with formatting use CTRL+SHIFT+V in libreOffice writer

Comment: @DennisG, Instant joy, until you are at your colleague's desk (or anyone else for that matter) and you found yourself so used to  CTRL+SHIFT+C that you've forgotten where the original setting is located. Whoops.

Comment: This worked for me except I was trying to preserve formatting in a `Notepad` file instead of an `MSWord` file.  I had to copy the code from `Notepad++`, paste it into `MSWord` and then copy it from `MSWord` and paste it into `Notepad`.  For some reason I could not paste it directly into `Notepad`.

Answer (score 34):

Select the Text

From the menu, go to Plugins > NPPExport > Copy RTF to clipboard

In MS Word go to Edit > Paste Special

This will open the Paste Special dialog box. Select the Paste radio button and from the list select Formatted Text (RTF)

You should be able to see the Formatted Text.

Answer (score 20):

Select the text.

Right Click.

Plugin Commands -> Copy Text with Syntax Highlighting

Paste it into Word or whatever.

Answer (score 12):

It is worth mentioning that **64-bit Notepad++ does not support Plugin Manager and NPPExport**, so they won't be shown in **Plugins** menu. If you will try to add *NPPExport* plugin manually, most likely you'll see :

> *"NPPExport plugin is not supported with 64bit Notepad++"*

Fortunately, there is [NPP_Export plugin](https://github.com/chcg/NPP_ExportPlugin) to download from [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/chcg/npp-exportplugin/build/job/l1eku4c71gtrwvh5/artifacts) which works well with 64-bit Notepad++ (v7.2.2 in my case) and support for *Plugin Manager* is underway (check [GitHub](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/issues/7) for updates).

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me that the best and easiest way is commented by *Dennis G*:

> And now go to [Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Plugin Commands > Copy all
>   Formats to clipboard] and set it to CTRL+SHIFT+C --> Instant joy.
>   CTRL+C to copy the raw text, CTRL+SHIFT+C to copy with formatting.
>   This should be default.

Hoping help someone just like me!

Comment: This is quite helpful, however, in my case, line endings and font types are not saved.

Answer (score 6):

For those who do not see Plugins->NPPExport,

Download Plugin Manager from [this](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases). Extract contents and place under C/ProgramFile/NP++ installation, plugins & updater folder. Restart NP++. You should be able to see Plugins->Plugin Manager then.
You can download any plugin, including NPPExport and install it to see the Copy command.

Answer (score 3):

As the chosen answer is pretty old, and things changed, here is the new procedure, if you use 64 bits Notepad++. 64 bits version does not come with Plugin Manager nor NppExport. All details provided [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2459).

To resume quickly, Plugin Manager is no longer develloped and NppExport can be found just [here](https://github.com/chcg/NPP_ExportPlugin/releases).

Answer (score -1):

I practised almost all methods sent by other users in this thread but in my opinion my solution works perfect. I pasted even content from Notepad++ but supports only one font. I decided to use native programs desired to make apps. I set in every code editor (Visual Studio, Intellij Idea, Android Studio, etc) my fav font so I copy source code from my environment program and paste code formatting to my documentation together (with font also). Looks great and clear
**The first image shows the view in Android Studio.**
[image: screenshot from Intellij Idea]

**The second image shows the pasted source code.  I just copied the selected part of source code and pasted to my document editor.**
[image: screenshot from document editor]

Comment: The images appear to show the results of your solution, but you have not described your solution or how to use it!

Comment: I updated the description

Answer (score -4):

**Horrible** to look for this failure:

**Copy .dll to here:**

*\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins --> put it here*

**Restart the notepad++**

and now you are able to use the copy commands!!!

Comment: What DLL would that be?