# Any web development applications that retains colour formatting when copying to word?

Tags: html, css, ms-word, copy

Any web development applications that retains colour formatting when copying to word?

I tried Netbeans, Dreamweaver CS5 and Notepad++ and it just give me default Word style. Don't really want to have to take a screenshot each time.

Comment: Does that recognise PHP/HTML/CSS/JavaScript though?

Comment: PHP with an addon (https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS457US457&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=visual+studio+php). HTML, CSS, and JavaScript: yes

Comment: Honestly, though, I'd stick with NetBeans. Maybe just copy and paste the code you want to colorize into VS then into Word. Or use an online colorizer. There might be some plugins floating around too (http://forums.netbeans.org/topic7825.html)

Comment: Im just thinking surely there are other computer science students and professionals who need to copy code into microsoft word to make reports..

Comment: How do I go about accepting an answer lol?

Comment: I actually haven't created an official answer yet, so I'll do that now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio does it, but I'm not sure about any others (Eclipse or Zend Studio maybe?). There has been some talk about plugins for Netbeans (http://forums.netbeans.org/topic7825.html), but I'm not sure if you will find anything recent.

My advice is to stick with whatever you are currently using, and either paste your code into Visual Studio for code colorization (and then into Word), or use an online colorizer.

Comment: That online colouriser is friggin awesome dude, thanks so much.

Comment: I will also try out the PHP plug in, installing it now but taking its time as usual ha

Comment: I hope you find something that works for you! If you do, please let us know what you've found.

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++ allows copying with format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475790/copy-notepad-text-with-formatting) from the menu.

Then I advise you link a key shortcut to it, like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for example.