# Copying Notepad++ code into PowerPoint 2010

Tags: ms-office, notepad++, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I've tried copying some source code that I have input into Notepad++ and pasting into PowerPoint 2010, but I'm not offered any "Paste Special" options other than "Keep Text Only"

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to preserve the syntax highlighting in your code, that question is answered here:
[Copy Notepad++ text with formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475790/copy-notepad-text-with-formatting)

I tested it out myself, and it seems to work best when you use the "Copy RTF to clipboard" option.

Comment: I've tried using the NppExport plug-ins, but the RTF style has undesirable results and the "all formatting option" requires me to have to do a lot of modifying once I paste it into PowerPoint. Was hoping for another solution.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "undesirable results"?  Your question hasn't specified exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The spacing for one is never left justified, even when I select those options. That is for the RTF method. For the "all formatting option" I have to put in my own line breaks, but at least everything justifies to the correct side.

Comment: After you pasted the text, did you select all of it before hitting the left-justify option?  It works for me when I paste RTF code into powerpoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have PP2010 to verify this, but in PP2007 there is a context help after you paste text that lets you switch between source and target formatting (target formatting being he default). Choosing source formatting should preserve highlighting (as well as font).