# RTF syntax highlighting in Doxygen

Tags: c++, ms-word, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I'm trying to create an RTF file to use in MS word of all the C++ files in my Visual Studio project. I'm using the most recent Doxygen and I set SOURCE_BROWSER to true, GENERATE_RTF to true, and RTF_SOURCE_CODE to true.

It says it will provide source code with syntax highlighting, but it just pastes all the code in Courier New font without any form of styling whatsoever. How can I get it to provide C++ syntax highlighting in its RTF output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475790/copy-notepad-text-with-formatting

Comment: Unfortunately that only works with 1 file - I would like to do it with all the files in my project at a time, and Doxygen also contains other useful information in its output.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed although stated in the documentation / Doxyfile the syntax highlighting was not implemented in doxygen.

I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 741, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/741) that implements the syntax highlighting for RTF.

2018/06/10: The push request has been integrated in the master version on github.