# Copy formatting from Notepad++ to OneNote 2016

Tags: notepad++, onenote

I'm following the instructions from this answer:

[Copy Notepad++ text with formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475790/copy-notepad-text-with-formatting)

The idea is to use the NppExport plug in to keep syntax formatting when you copy/paste from Notepad++ (there are different ways to do it - great answers over there).

Everything works as expected when pasting code into, say, Word 2016.  But when pasting into OneNote 2016 it appears to trim CR/LFs.  It works if I first paste into Word, then copy/paste from Word to OneNote.

1 picture == 1k words:

[image]

Why doesn't it work with OneNote and what can I do about it?

Comment: No idea how to solve you problem. But if you only want to highlight code in onenote. Maybe you can try this plugin http://notehighlight2013.codeplex.com/releases/view/615734

Comment: @CongMa - this is what I was using before upgrading to OneNote 2016.  It stopped working after the upgrade.

Comment: em, I'm using OneNote 2016 too. It's sad that it cannot highlight SQL on my machine either. I only used  js, c# and c++ before and they worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

I could not find any straightforward solution, but it is possible to copy formatted code to MS Word and copy from Word to OneNote.